# Apache Flink Process Stream Multiple Times

Tags: java, apache-flink

I am trying to use Apache Flink to process a data stream using two different algorithms. My pseudo code is as follows:

```
env = getEnvironment();
DataStream<Event> inputStream = getInputStream();
// How to replicate the input stream?
Array[DataStream<Event>] inputStreams = inputStream.clone()

// apply different operations on the replicated streams
outputOne = inputStreams[0].map(func1);
outputTwo = inputStreams[1].map(func2);
 ...
outputOne.addSink(sink1);
outputTwo.addSink(sink2);
env.execute();
```

I did some research with Flink documentation. It seems there is no concept of cloning a stream. Neither [DataStream.iterate()](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/scala/DataStream.html#iterate-scala.Function1-long-org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation-) nor [DataStream.split()](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/scala/DataStream.html#split-scala.Function1-) are doing exactly what I want. Is there an alternative to creating a stream multiple times from its source? Thank you for your help.

Comment: This answer may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47750597/reuse-of-a-stream-is-a-copy-of-stream-or-not

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Cloning" a stream is quite simple and does not require a dedicated operator. You can just apply multiple transformation on the same `DataStream`. All downstream transformations will consume the complete stream.

So in your example you do:

```
env = getEnvironment();
DataStream<Event> inputStream = getInputStream();

outputOne = inputStream.map(func1); // apply 1st transformation
outputTwo = inputStream.map(func2); // apply 2nd transformation
...
outputOne.addSink(sink1);
outputTwo.addSink(sink2);
env.execute();
```

Comment: Thanks, I assumed that once a inputStream.map has been called, the inputStream instance is not usable anymore. So, Flink DataStreams can be reused?