# Does flink streaming have cache/persist feature? (like spark)

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I have a Flink streaming program that have branch processing logic after a long transformation logic. Will the long transformation logic be executed multiple times? Pseudo code:

```
env = getEnvironment();
DataStream<Event> inputStream = getInputStream();

tempStream = inputStream.map(very_heavy_computation_func)

output1 = tempStream.map(func1);
output1.addSink(sink1);

output2 = tempStream.map(func2);
output2.addSink(sink2);

env.execute();
```

Questions:

- How many times would `inputStream.map(very_heavy_computation_func)` be executed?
- Once or twice?
- If twice, how can I cache `tempStream` (or other method) to avoid the previous transformation being executed multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually answer (1) easily by just trying out more or less exactly your example:

```java
public class TestProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        SingleOutputStreamOperator<Integer> stream = env.fromElements(1, 2, 3)
                .map(i -> {
                    System.out.println("Executed expensive computation for: " + i);
                    return i;
                });

        stream.map(i -> i).addSink(new PrintSinkFunction<>());
        stream.map(i -> i).addSink(new PrintSinkFunction<>());

        env.execute();
    }
}
```

produces (on my machine, for example):

```
Executed expensive computation for: 3
Executed expensive computation for: 1
Executed expensive computation for: 2
9> 3
8> 2
8> 2
9> 3
7> 1
7> 1
```

You can also find a more technical answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47751737/1675492) which explains how records are replicated to downstream operators, rather than running the source/operator multiple times.